# Speed up MySQL ?

Tags: mysql, batch-file, insert

I have a working project, but i want to tune it a bit

I use a batch: `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql --force -u user -ppass database1 < C:\some\import.sql`

The file `import.sql` is a file that contains insert-statements. Each file is about 30MB of size, and it gets exponentally bigger. here is a data example (very basic)

```
ID |   DATE   | TEST
1     1-1-14     Y
2     1-2-14     Y
```

For each date, a few entries get added.
Yesterday `49999 Lines` in the file

Today `50002 Lines in the file` 
So, i only really need 3 Lines of that file! And my batch "errors" on 49999 lines, that there is a duplicate line.

Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: MySQL instituted incremental backup/restore a few rev's back. Whatever it is your doing is like a full restore (but I have done that with over > 50k rows and a lot more columns than you and never had an issue - my file is only slightly > 5MB). Or as Ollie said (if possible) - modify your system to use LOAD DATA INFILE.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to give advice on speeding up SQL without knowing what the SQL says. There are all kinds of complex factors to take into account. You could consider editing your question to show more details.

The fastest way to bulk-load data into a MySQL server is to use the [`LOAD DATA INFILE` command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html). That command reads data from a flat file like a CSV or tab-separated value file directly into a table. It doesn't work with files of SQL commands.

Comment: Well, you could type faster. That would help. ;-)